# OSGi DS: Why is setService called before activate

Tags: java, osgi

I have a OSGi DS component with properties defined and which is referencing another bundles service. In the `setService` method I get the reference of the other's bundle service and start another thread. I'm dependent on properties defined in `component.xml`. Thus the first time I'm able to read the properties from the component.xml file is after the bundle gets the `activated` method called and getting the reference of the `ComponentContext`. Now it seems I have serious timing problems, as the `setService` is executed before the `activate` is executed.

- How can that be? How can the bundle get the required service references before it is even activated?
- How can I access the properties defined in the component.xml when starting the thread in the setService method?

The concrete example:

```
private String publishingUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:11023/ws"; // default address

protected synchronized void activate(ComponentContext context) {
    this.ctx = context;
    if (ctx != null) {
        String url = String.valueOf(ctx.getProperties().get("publishingUrl"));
        if (url != null) publishingUrl = url;
    }
    logger.info("Activated and got the publishingUrl: "+ publishingUrl);
}

public void setService(AnotherService service) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (this.anotherService == service) {
            logger.info("anotherService was already set.");
            return;
        } else {
            this.anotherService = service;
            logger.info("Got anotherService. Thank you DS!");
        }
    }
    startWebserviceThread(publishingUrl);
}
```

In the console ouput I see the logger message from the `setService`, then from `activate`. The method `startWebserviceThread` is always called with the default value of `publishingUrl` not with the one got from the ComponentContext property file.

Also it doesn't make a difference if I set `immediate="true"` or `immediate="false"` in component.xml

Runtime: Java 1.6, eclipse equinox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setService()` method is used to inject dependencies into your DS.
Then `activate()` is called, and it is the place where the worker thread should start.

You have to move `startWebserviceThread(publishingUrl)`; at the end of `activate()` method.

This is also suggested by your logic. You get the publishing url setting from your context, and then you can start your web service. To use another service, you need its reference *before* starting, so this is why `setService()` is called before `activate()`.

As noted in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html#tutorial_ds), a service should not be used inside set/unset methods.

Comment: OK, it seems I had another understanding of the execution order. In my opinion the activate method should be the first method in any way called and then react on setting/unsetting dependant services.
But your explanation definitly makes sense (and of course it worked as you suggested).

Comment: You don't mention, but I assume your reference to AnotherService is a static policy reference. Static policy references are always injected before the activate method is called. Dynamic policy references can be injected after the activate method is called.